# Opening console from shell script and giving command to the opened console from the shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to write the script file command.sh
as follows (only single line):

```
konsole cd /home/user/temp/
```

I want to open a console from this shell script and want to do a change directory to temp with the opened console.

When I executed this shell script it was able to only open console not do a cd.

(Note : I want to change directory in the new console opened by executing the script and not the console in which I am executing the script(current console))

Comment: superuser.com might have the answer

Answer (score 1):

From the [Handbook](http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kdebase-apps/konsole/command-line-options.html):

```
konsole --workdir dir
```